# Create a 'beginswith' NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I am trying to create an NSPredicate that searches through an array, then checks to see whether  any objects in that array start with other string. Here is my code. It gave me a crash, so apparently something is wrong.

```
array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello", @"What", @"Maybe", nil];

NSString *string = @"H";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ BEGINSWITH %@", string, array];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

Here is the crash error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = H rhs = (
    Hello,
    What,
    Maybe
))'
```

It then gave a bunch of numbers in the error, I can post that if you'd like, just let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is. Look at the error. Then look at your code:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ BEGINSWITH %@", string, array]
```

How could a *string* ever begin with an *array*? Your predicate is nonsense.

So that is one source of difficulty - you are not bothering to read the error message. The other source of difficulty is that you are not bothering to read the docs. You haven't stopped to learn what an NSPredicate format actually is. The documentation is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

I think in your case what you want to say, surely, is something more sensible, like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@", string]
```

Give that a try and see if it gets the results you expect.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! By the way, I did read both, it's just that I'm a beginner, and I don't totally understand everything. But thanks. You really helped me gain a deeper understanding in NSPredicate